# Fake PCI Device for Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, linux-device-driver, virtualization, pci

## Background

I am working on a project that has a PCI card connected to a Linux computer. The PCI card is a custom card and, as such the Linux computer has a custom driver.

We have recently switched to virtual machines for our software development environment. It would be a huge help to be able to mimic the functionality of the PCI device in a way in which the VM could interact.

## Question

Is there a way to create a fake/virtual PCI device that would interface with the development Virtual Machine? The "virtual device" would ideally be software that ran on the Virtual Machine host (the developer's computer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to face a similar problem when trying to add a sound card to my windows server virtual machine whhich is based on vmware. And that can't be done because the cluster itself did not contain such device to be allocated to my virtual machine.
Your virtual machine provider can handle such issue.
[example with vmware](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vmadmin.doc_41/vc_client_help/managing_virtual_machine_hardware_and_devices/t_add_passthrough_device.html)

So what you can also do is to look for software emulator for you PCI card.

Comment: Thanks @Kassav'. Your answer seems consistent with my other research on the subject. I'm going to wait a little while to mark your response as the answer, just in case someone has actually been able to do this.

Comment: It seems that no one has been able to do this. Thank you for confirming that this is not currently possible @Kassav'